# Handling multiple socket communication in Python Client-Server application

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, socket

I'm developing a client-server game application in Python. Here's the scenario:

Clients connect to the server and register.
After registration, all clients see a main menu.
One client can initiate a game, selecting a number of players (x).
The selected clients should transition to an in-game state and receive new messages related to the game.

Issue:

The client that initiates the game transitions into the in-game state immediately. However, the other selected clients are still waiting for user input in the main menu. Once they provide input, they then transition to the in-game state. I want all selected clients to transition to the in-game state simultaneously.

"Server" Program:

```
import random
from threading import Thread
import socket
import json
import sys

from game import Card, Game

game_state = {'player_data': {}, 'games': {}}
client_connections = {}
class Manager():
    STATE_MAIN_MENU = 'main_menu'
    STATE_IN_GAME = 'in_game'
    def __init__(self):
        self.playerList = {}
        self.games = {}
        self.player_states = {}
        self.player_to_game = {}  # Maps a player's name to a game ID
        self.game_id_counter = 0

    def set_state(self, player, state):
        self.player_states[player] = state

    def get_state(self, player):
        return self.player_states.get(player, self.STATE_MAIN_MENU)

    def register(self, player, ip4, mport, rport, pport, game_state):
        if player in self.playerList:
            return "FAILURE"
        self.playerList[player] = {'ip4': ip4, 'mport': mport, 'rport': rport, 'pport': pport}
        game_state['player_data'][player] = {'ip4': ip4, 'mport': mport, 'rport': rport, 'pport': pport}
        self.set_state(player, self.STATE_MAIN_MENU)
        return "SUCCESS"

    def start_game(self, dealer, k, game_state):
        k = int(k)  # Make sure k is an integer
        if dealer not in self.playerList or len(self.playerList) < k or k > 5:
            print(dealer + "DEALERINFO\n")
            for x in self.playerList:
                print(x + "HELP")
            print(f"Comparing dealer '{dealer}' with playerList keys {list(self.playerList.keys())}")
            return "FAILURE", None

        available_players = [player for player in self.playerList.keys() if self.get_state(player) != self.STATE_IN_GAME and player != dealer]
        selected_players = random.sample(available_players, k - 1)

        self.game_id_counter += 1
        # Create the list of 5-tuples for the dealer and selected players
        five_tuples = [{"player": dealer, **self.playerList[dealer]}]
        for player in selected_players:
            five_tuples.append({"player": player, **self.playerList[player]})

        # Initialize Game and setup the logical ring
        game = Game(dealer, selected_players, self.playerList)
        game.setup_logical_ring(five_tuples)  # Pass the 5-tuples to setup_logical_ring

        self.games[self.game_id_counter] = game
        game_state['games'][self.game_id_counter] = {'dealer': dealer,
                                                     'players': {key: self.playerList[key] for key in selected_players}}

        game_id = self.game_id_counter
        self.player_to_game[dealer] = game_id
        for player in selected_players:
            self.player_to_game[player] = game_id

        # Update player states
        for player in selected_players:
            self.set_state(player, self.STATE_IN_GAME)
        self.set_state(dealer, self.STATE_IN_GAME)

        # Notify players in the new game
        for player_name in selected_players:
            player_conn = client_connections.get(player_name)
            if player_conn:
                player_conn.sendall(generate_message('YOU ARE NOW IN A GAME!!!!!!!\n Press "6" to acknowledge.\n'))

        return "SUCCESS"

    def query_players(self):
        if len(self.playerList) == 0:
            return "There are no players!"
        else:
            player_count = len(self.playerList)
            player_info_list = []

            for player_name in self.playerList.keys():
                state = self.player_states.get(player_name, "")
                if "IN_GAME" in state:
                    player_info_list.append(f"{player_name}\tIN GAME")
                else:
                    player_info_list.append(player_name)

            formatted_players = "\n".join(player_info_list)

            print("PLAYER STATES")
            for x in self.player_states:
                print(x + " " + self.player_states[x])
            print("\n")
            return f"Total players: {player_count}\nPlayers:\n{formatted_players}"

    def query_games(self):
        if len(self.games) == 0:
            return "There are no games!"
        else:
            game_count = len(self.games)
            game_list = []
            for game_id, game in self.games.items():
                dealer = game.dealer
                players = ", ".join(game.players)
                game_list.append(f"Game ID: {game_id}, Dealer: {dealer}, Players: {players}")

            formatted_games = "\n".join(game_list)
            return f"Total games: {game_count}\nGames:\n{formatted_games}"

    def dereg(self, player, game_state):
        if player in self.playerList:
            del self.playerList[player]
            if player in game_state['player_data']:
                del game_state['player_data'][player]
            return "SUCCESS"
        return "FAILURE"

def state_main_menu(conn, manager, clientName):
    msg = generate_message(
        '1: Register\n2: Start Game\n3: Query Players\n4: Query Games\n5: De-register Player\n6: Exit\n',
        True)
    conn.sendall(msg)
    choice = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

    if choice == '1':
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Please enter your name:\n', True, 'register'))

        client_data_json = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
        try:
            client_data = json.loads(client_data_json)
            clientName = client_data.get('name', '')
            ip4 = client_data.get('ip4', '')
            mport = client_data.get('mport', '')
            rport = client_data.get('rport', '')
            pport = client_data.get('pport', '')
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Invalid JSON received for registration. Ignoring.")
        result = manager.register(clientName, ip4, mport, rport, pport, game_state)
        if result == "SUCCESS":
            for player, info in game_state['player_data'].items():
                print(f"Player: {player}")
                print(f"  IP Address: {info['ip4']}")
                print(f"  mport: {info['mport']}")
                print(f"  rport: {info['rport']}")
                print(f"  pport: {info['pport']}")
            print(manager.query_players())
            return clientName

    elif choice == '2':
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Please enter your name:\n', True))
        playerName = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

        conn.sendall(generate_message('Please enter the amount of players:\n', True))
        numPlayers = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

        result = manager.start_game(playerName, numPlayers, game_state)
        if result == "SUCCESS":
            print(manager.query_games())

        else:
            conn.sendall(generate_message('Unable to start game.\n'))

    elif choice == '3':
        print(manager.query_players())
        conn.sendall(generate_message(manager.query_players()))

    elif choice == '4':
        print(manager.query_games())
        conn.sendall(generate_message(manager.query_games()))

    elif choice == '5':
        conn.sendall(generate_message('Are you sure you want to de-register a player?\n1: Yes\n2: No\n', True))
        leaveMessage = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()

        while True:
            if leaveMessage == '1':
                conn.sendall(generate_message('Enter the player being de-registered:\n', True))
                playerGone = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
                result = manager.dereg(playerGone, game_state)
                if result == "SUCCESS":
                    conn.sendall(generate_message('PLAYER DE REG!\n'))
                break
            elif leaveMessage == '2':
                break
            else:
                conn.sendall(generate_message('Invalid selection, try again\n 1: Yes\n 2: No\n', True))
                leaveMessage = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
    elif choice == '6':
        pass
    else:
        conn.sendall(generate_message(f'Invalid choice. Try again. Your choice: {choice}\n'))
    return clientName

def state_in_game(conn, manager,clientName,game_id):
    game = manager.games[game_id]

    msg = generate_message('In-Game:\n1: Deal Cards (if dealer)\n2: View Hand\n3: End Turn\n4: Quit\n', True)
    conn.sendall(msg)
    choice = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
    if choice == '1':
        game.shuffle_deck()
        print("Deck shuffled.\n")
        game.deal_initial_cards()
        print("Cards Dealt\n")

        #notify dealer
        msg = generate_message('You successfully dealt the cards.\n')
        conn.sendall(msg)
        # Notify all players
        notify_msg = generate_message("You have been dealt cards.\n")
        for player in game.players:
            player_conn = client_connections.get(player)
            if player_conn:
                player_conn.sendall(notify_msg)
    elif choice == '2':
        hand = game.get_player_hand(clientName)
        hand_str = ', '.join(hand)
        conn.sendall(generate_message(f"Your hand: {hand_str}\n"))
        pass
    elif choice == '3':
        # TODO: Logic to end the player's turn and move to the next player
        pass
    elif choice == '4':
        # TODO: Logic to quit the game
        pass

def handle_client(conn, addr, manager):
    try:
        print(f"Connected to {addr}")
        clientName = None  # unique identifier for the client

        while True:
            print(f"{clientName}  CLIENT")
            if clientName:
                state = manager.get_state(clientName)
                game_id = manager.player_to_game.get(clientName, None)  # Get game_id
                client_connections[clientName] = conn
            else:
                state = manager.STATE_MAIN_MENU

            if state == manager.STATE_IN_GAME:
                state_in_game(conn, manager,clientName, game_id)
            else:
                clientName = state_main_menu(conn, manager, clientName)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling client {addr}: {e}")

def generate_message(message, expect_reply=False, msg_type=None):
    msg_dict = {'message': message, 'expect_reply': expect_reply}
    if msg_type:
        msg_dict['type'] = msg_type
    return json.dumps(msg_dict).encode('utf-8')

def start_server(host, port, manager):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)  # Allow up to 5 pending connections
    server_socket.settimeout(1)  # 1-second timeout
    print(f"Server listening on {host}:{port}")

    try:
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
            except socket.timeout:
                continue

            print(f"Connection from {addr}")
            t1 = Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr, manager))
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nShutting down server.")
        server_socket.close()
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python manager.py <port>")
        sys.exit(1)

    port = int(sys.argv[1])
    manager = Manager()
    start_server('0.0.0.0', port, manager)  # Listen on all available interfaces
```

"Client" Program:

```
import socket
import sys
import json
import random
import threading

# Shared variable
last_message_type = None

def listen_for_messages(sock):
    global last_message_type
    while True:
        try:
            received_data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not received_data:
                print("No data received. Connection might be closed.")
                break

            json_data = json.loads(received_data)
            print(f"Server says:\n{json_data['message']}")
            last_message_type = json_data.get('type', None)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Listener error: {e}")
            break

def send_messages(sock, ip4, mport, rport, pport):
    global last_message_type
    while True:
        client_input = input("Your input: ")
        if last_message_type == 'register':
            client_input = json.dumps({
                'name': client_input,
                'ip4': ip4,
                'mport': mport,
                'rport': rport,
                'pport': pport
            })
        sock.sendall(client_input.encode('utf-8'))

class Client():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_socket.connect((host, port))

    def run(self):
        try:
            print(f"Connected to {self.host}:{self.port}")

            # Automatically set IP and random ports
            ip4 = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
            mport = random.randint(5000, 6000)
            rport = random.randint(6001, 7000)
            pport = random.randint(7001, 8000)

            # Start the listener thread
            listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_messages, args=(self.client_socket,))
            listener_thread.daemon = True
            listener_thread.start()

            # Start the sender thread
            sender_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_messages, args=(self.client_socket, ip4, mport, rport, pport))
            sender_thread.daemon = True
            sender_thread.start()

            # Keep the main thread running
            while True:
                pass

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Client error: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python client.py <server_ip> <server_port>")
        sys.exit(1)

    server_ip = sys.argv[1]
    server_port = int(sys.argv[2])

    client_instance = Client(server_ip, server_port)
    client_instance.run()
```

I have a 3rd file as well, but those are just for game functions and do not really relate to client-client communication, or sending/receiving on multiple sockets.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to synchronize the client state transitions?
I am struggling with dealing with clients communicating each other and handling messages to and from each other, and overall handling multiple sockets and maintaining track of message and response orders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## sleep

This is just insane:

```
            # Keep the main thread running
            while True:
                pass
```

Instead of heating up a core, prefer to sleep() for a while.
That yields to the scheduler,
so it can locate a thread that is ready to run.

---

## catch errors you know how to handle

```
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Client error: {e}")
```

This looks more like java code than python.
Consider just letting the exception bubble up the call stack
so we get an informative traceback diagnostic.
Similarly for your other `try` + `print` error "handlers".

---

## use open intervals

In client `run` these three are inconsistent:

```
            mport = random.randint(5000, 6000)
            rport = random.randint(6001, 7000)
            pport = random.randint(7001, 8000)
```

Rather than mess around with sometimes using `+ 1`, prefer to use
[randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
            mport = random.randrange(5000, 6000)
            rport = random.randrange(6000, 7000)
            pport = random.randrange(7000, 8000)
```

---

## serving round robin

> other selected clients are still waiting for user input in the main menu.

It sounds like you want to
"import [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html)"
so you can await the event that happens first.
It will be "data on X is now available",
where either X is `sys.stdin` or is the network TCP connection.